# Displaying content of a prompt pop-up in a text-box?

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, popup, prompt

I am trying to get the user to enter their name, which will then be displayed in a textbox. I am having difficulty and believe i am only missing something small?

my HTML for the coding is:

```
Name <input type="text" value=myFunctioning/>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is working. I tested it.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunctioning()
{
var x;
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","");

if (name!=null)
{
x=name;
document.getElementById("demo").value=x;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunctioning()">
<input type="text" id="demo"/>
</body>
</html>
```